# An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/src/tooling'

Tags: angular, angular-cli, npm-install, tooling

When ever i try to run the project (npx ng serve -o) i get a error.

An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/src/tooling'

> {
> "name": "LandTransfer",
> "version": "0.0.0",
> "scripts": {
> "ng": "ng",
> "start": "ng serve",
> "build": "ng build",
> "test": "ng test --watch=false",
> "lint": "ng lint",
> "e2e": "ng e2e",
> "postinstall": "node patch.js"
> },
> "private": true,
> "dependencies": {
> "@angular/animations": "7.1.0",
> "@angular/cdk": "^7.1.0",
> "@angular/common": "7.1.0",
> "@angular/compiler": "^7.1.0",
> "@angular/core": "7.1.0",
> "@angular/forms": "7.1.0",
> "@angular/material": "^7.1.0",
> "@angular/platform-browser": "7.1.0",
> "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.1.0",
> "@angular/platform-server": "7.1.0",
> "@angular/router": "7.1.0",
> "@angular/service-worker": "^7.1.0",
> "autoprefixer": "^10.0.2",
> "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
> "bufferutil": "^4.0.1",
> "core-js": "^2.5.7",
> "ethers": "^4.0.20",
> "jquery": "^1.9.1",
> "less": "^2.3.1",
> "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
> "rxjs": "6.3.3",
> "stylus": "^0.52.4",
> "tailwindcss": "^2.0.0",
> "truffle-contract": "^4.0.1",
> "tslib": "^2.0.0",
> "typedarray-to-buffer": "^3.1.5",
> "utf-8-validate": "^5.0.2",
> "web3": "1.0.0-beta.37",
> "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
> },
> "devDependencies": {
> "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.3",
> "@angular-devkit/core": "0.8.1",
> "@angular/cli": "^11.2.3",
> "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.1.0",
> "@angular/language-service": "7.1.0",
> "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
> "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
> "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
> "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
> "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
> "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
> "karma": "~5.0.0",
> "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
> "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
> "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
> "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
> "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
> "protractor": "~7.0.0",
> "protractor-console-plugin": "^0.1.1",
> "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
> "tslint": "~6.1.0",
> "typescript": "^3.1.1",
> "webpack": "^4.26.1",
> "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
> },
> "optionalDependencies": {
> "fsevents": "^1.2.13"
> }
> }

Answer (score 0):

There is maybe something wrong with your `node_moduels`, try if this works:

```
   rm -rf node_modules

   npm install
```

It will remove your node_modules/ folder and then reinstall the dependencies from package.json.